# Is there a way to get the probability of a prediction using XGBoostRegressor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I have built a XGBoostRegressor model using around 200 categorical features predicting a countinous time variable.

But I would want to get both the actual prediction and the probability of that prediction as output. Is there any way to get this from the XGBoostRegressor model?

So I both want [image: \hat{y}] and P(Y|X) as output. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You could look at the argument `...output_margin=True`, of the [predict method](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn)

Comment: What does this give you in the case of regression?

Comment: I don't know, but was wondering what it would give out! I'm not really familiar with XGBoost

Answer (score 2):

There is no probability in regression, In regression the only output you will get is a predicted value thats why it is called regression, so for any regressor probability of a prediction is not possible. Its only there in classification.

Comment: I was thinking something similar to CDF, because xgboost must have done something like this right? Maybe something like what is the probability that the prediction will be 100 minutes, +/- 5 minutes.

Comment: i thought a lot but "what is the probability that the prediction will be 100 minutes, +/- 5 minutes." this is not possible, but yes you fan find a probability value based on CDF given your prediction is 100 minutes. Or else you can find confidence interval for your predictions based on mean and standard deviation.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. You do have probabilities in regression models, in fact this is the standard output of logistic regression. But beyond that, when you perform linear regression you assume a probabilistic distribution for your residuals, you can compute confidence intervals for your prediction which has also an underlying distribution. The probability of predicting a specific real value is zero though, so what you really want is a probabilistic model that provides confidence intervals. See gio.visani  answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to look into Ngboost (essentially a wrapper of Xgboost which provides eventually a [probabilistic model](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probabilistic/#:%7E:text=A%20probabilistic%20method%20or%20model,the%20added%20complication%20of%20randomness.).
Here you can find [slides](https://drive.google.com/file/d/183BWFAdFms81MKy6hSku8qI97OwS_JH_/view) on the Ngboost functioning and the [seminal Ngboost paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/duan20a/duan20a.pdf).

The basic idea is to assume a specific distribution for $P(Y|X=x)$ (by default is the Gaussian distribution) and fit an Xgboost model to estimate the best parameters of the distribution (for the Gaussian $\mu$ and $\sigma$. The model will split the variables' space into different regions with different distributions, i.e. same family (eg. Gaussian) but different parameters.

After training the model, you're provided with the method '''pred_dist''' which returns the estimated distribution $P(Y|X=x)$ for a given set of values $x$

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, there is no probability associated with regression.

However, you could probably add a [confidence interval](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/statmistakes/CIvsPI.html) on that regression, to see whether or not your regression can be trusted.

One thing to note though, is that the variance might not be the same along the data.
Let's assume that you study a time based phenomenon. Specifically, you have the temperature (y) after (x) time (in sec for instance) inside an oven. At x = 0s it is at 20°C, and you start heating it, and want to know the evolution in order to predict the temperature after x seconds. The variance could be the same after 20 seconds and after 5 minutes, or be completely different. This is called [heteroscedasticity](https://datascienceplus.com/how-to-detect-heteroscedasticity-and-rectify-it/).

If you want to use a confidence interval, you probably want to make sure that you took care of heteroscedasticity, so your interval is the same for all the data.

You can probably try to get the distribution of your known outputs and compare the prediction on that curve, and check the pvalue. But that would only give you a measure of how realistic it is to get that output, without taking the input into consideration. If you know your inputs/outputs are in a specific interval, this could work.

- EDIT 
  This is how I would do it. Obviously the outputs are your real outputs.

  `import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from scipy import integrate
  from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
  N = 1000  # The number of sample
  mean = 0
  std = 1
  outputs = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std, size=N)
   # We want to get a normed histogram (since this is PDF, if we integrate 
   # it must be equal to 1)
  nbins = N / 10
  n = int(N / nbins)
  p, x = np.histogram(outputs, bins=n, normed=True)
  plt.hist(outputs, bins=n, normed=True)
  x = x[:-1] + (x[ 1] - x[0])/2   # converting bin edges to centers
   # Now we want to interpolate :
   # f = CubicSpline(x=x, y=p, bc_type='not-a-knot')
  f = interp1d(x=x, y=p, kind='quadratic', fill_value='extrapolate')
  x = np.linspace(-2.9*std, 2.9*std, 10000)
  plt.plot(x, f(x))
  plt.show()
   # To check :
  area = integrate.quad(f, x[0], x[-1])
  print(area)  # (should be close to 1)`

[image: This is what I get from the method above.]

Now, the interpolate method is not great for outliers. if a predicted data is extremely far (more than 3 times the std) from your distribution, it wont work. Other than that, you can now use the PDF to get meaningful results.

It is not perfect, but it is the best I came up with in that time. I'm sure there are some better ways to do it. If your data follow a normal law, it becomes trivial.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I only have categorical input variables though. Is it still possible to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data you are working with ?
I'd like to see what can be done.

Comment: Well I can't really give a sample data, I am not allowed to share it. But it is data on different products. "Product name","product category","design country" and so on. And the target variable is how long it takes to release a product.

Comment: I see, then a confidence interval might not be great.
However, you can still create a Probability Density Function (PDF) from the output (the time to release), and compare the expected value to this PDF. if your data are representative of the reality, then you could have an idea on how realistic it is. 
Note that the PDF needs to be compared to a plot of the actual data, to check how well it is.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Do you have any tips on how to construct such a PDF from the output of my xgb model?Would it be possible to construct a PDF which is dependent on all my input variables? Such that I would pull an estimate from a different distribution for different inputs.

Comment: The PDF I have in mind wont take into consideration the input values, but will give an idea of the probability of such output overall, which could be a good indication.

I'll do an example code in python and will provide it as another answer for the sake of clarity.